# Mask certain indices for every entry in a batch, when using torch.max()

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am incremently sampling a `batch` of size `torch.Size([n, 8])`.

I also have a list `valid_indices` of length n which contains tuples of indices that are valid for each entry in the batch.

For instance `valid_indices[0]` may look like this: `(0,1,3,4,5,7)` , which suggests that indices 2 and 6 should be excluded from the first entry in `batch` along dim 1.

Particularly I need to exclude these values for when I use `torch.max(batch, dim=1, keepdim=True)`.

Indices to be excluded (if any) may differ from entry to entry within the batch.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are getting the good old

```
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
```

error when you use your tuple indices directly on the tensor.
At least that was the error that I was able to reproduce when I execute the following line

```
 t[0][valid_idx0]
```

Where t is a random tensor with size (10,8) and valid_idx0 is a tuple with 4 elements.

However, same line works just fine when you convert your tuple to a list as following

```
 t[0][list(valid_idx0)]

 >>> tensor([0.1847, 0.1028, 0.7130, 0.5093])
```

But when it comes to applying these indices to 2D tensors, things get a bit different, since we need to preserve the structure of our tensor for batch processing.

Therefore, it would be reasonable to **convert our indices to mask arrays**.

Let's say we have a list of tuples `valid_indices` at hand. First thing will be converting it to a list of lists.

```
valid_idx_list = [list(tup) for tup in valid_indices]
```

Second thing will be converting them to mask arrays.

```
masks = np.zeros((t.size()))
for i, indices in enumerate(valid_idx_list):
  masks[i][indices] = 1
```

Done. Now we can apply our mask and use the torch.max on the masked tensor.

```
torch.max(t*masks)
```

Kindly see the colab notebook that I've used to reproduce the problem.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BhKKgxk3gRwUjM8ilmiqgFvo0sfXMGiK?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have done this, however I am wondering how I can apply the list of varying tuples to a batch Tensor, or somehow use it to exclude indices when using Torch.max.

Comment: Many thanks Bedir, this seems to work! I should have mentioned that I can also have negative values, but for this I replaced the 0s with -1e10 which works for my use case.

Comment: My pleasure. Great to know that I was able to help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I wanted to confirm. If you have those negative values in your training batch, it should be ok for this max operation. For the zeros, I am curious about the rationale behind replacing them with -1e10.

Comment: Quite often in the training process, all values may be negative (Q-value estimates for RL), so I'd assume that by zeroing the ones that I want to exclude.. these would inadvertently be chosen by torch.max, so I replaced the zeros with a large negative number, -1e10.